# How high charging temperature causes damage to AA size NiMH cell

Tags: batteries, battery-charging, temperature, charger, nimh

I used a portable thermometer and put on top of a battery charger. I notice that the temperature reach 39 degree Celsius and I can feel the warmth when I put my hand on top of the charger & the battery & the thermometer.

According to the charger instruction, it mention that it will disconnect itself if it get to 40 degree Celsius. Also, from my understanding, battery life are reduce if they are used in a hot environment.

So, I would like to know at what temperature can cause what type of degree of damage to the battery?

I listed a table below as follows (for illustrations and is **NOT** the actual data):

```
====================================================
|  Temp. (Celsius) |  Damages                       |
=====================================================
|  0 to 10         |  No damage                     |
| 10 to 20         |  Recharge cycle drop 1%        |
| 21 to 25         |                                |
| 26 to 30         |                                |
| Above 31         |  Battery life shorten by 10%   |
=====================================================
```

**energizer rechargeable batteries AA Size 2000 mAH**

[image]

**eneloop rechargeable batteries AA Size 2000 mAH**

[image]

Comment: Depends entirely on the battery, each manufacturer will be different in materials/quality, each type will be designed with a certain specification, and each individual battery will behave differently due to its different use/life.

Comment: Please specify which batteries were involved - specific model number and brand. If you have a datasheet for the battery, that would help too.

Comment: @AnindoGhosh Eneloop and energizer.

Comment: @Jack Model numbers? Energizer for instance offers at least two AA options, [E91 Alkaline](http://data.energizer.com/PDFs/e91.pdf) and [L91 Lithium](http://data.energizer.com/PDFs/l91.pdf), neither being recharegable. If you are going to make everyone guess, that just wastes people's time, and calls for votes to close the question. Also, edit your question to add detail, not in comments.

Comment: Eneloop, eneloop xx, eneloop lite, eneloop spy sattelite battery you bought on eBay?
If you dig round you might find data sheets for the batteries you're using, like this: http://docs-europe.electrocomponents.com/webdocs/0030/0900766b800303b7.pdf

Comment: @Jack please edit your question to be more specific, so people don't have to read the comments.

Comment: @AnindoGhosh, I can't find the data sheet for energizer rechargeable batteries.

Comment: @Jack Here you go: http://data.energizer.com/PDFs/HR6-2000_EU.pdf

Comment: At an extreme, overheating can cause venting some of the electrolyte through the pressure relief often present on consumer-market cells.  That reduces the amount left in the cell...  It would be interesting to have answers which could explain other possible partial damage mechanisms.

Comment: Thanks Anindo Ghosh for the link and I do agree with Chris Stratton comment on `It would be interesting to have answers which could explain other possible partial damage mechanisms.`

Answer (score 1):

Charging NiMH cell will cause it's temperature to rise. The rise of  temperature is directly proportional to the cell charging current.

An intelligent charger can charge a battery or cell at high current but may also senses the temperature. If the temperature exceeds the preset value, the current is reduced.

Generally the charging temperature is in between 20-40 degrees centigrade depending upon the size (A, AA, AAA, etc) of the battery. Cell manufacturer usually specifies this acceptable range.

High charging temperatures reduce the life of the cell! 40 degrees is almost damaging temp. Unless needed, cells / batteries should be charged at the lowest current possible (check datasheet).

Recommendations:
1. Charge cells/batteries in well ventilated areas with lower temp.
2. Invest in a good *intelligent* charger. I have used Rayovac (died after 4-5 years), Eneloop and Tenergy
3. Condition cells time to time for a longer life of the cell.
4. If charger allows normal / slow charge over fast charge, use that setting unless needed.
5. If your charger does not monitor temperature, and the area is not well ventilated, adding a small fan will help elongate the life of the cell.